# Windows Embedded Compact 7 Connection Manager

Tags: c#, c++, wifi, windows-embedded-compact

We're attempting to write a code base in C++ for connecting to Wifi programatically in WEC 7. We started out using Native Wifi, but reached a snag when we found that, if Connection Manager is installed, Native Wifi will always return Access Denied errors when attempting to connect.

We have attempting to build a version of WEC 7 without Connection Manager, but our WEC 7 person is reporting that whenever she includes Wifi as part of the OS image, Connection Manager is automatically selected.

As such, we are currently attempting to work with Connection Manager.

My Questions are thus:

1) Can Native Wifi be made to work even if Connection Manager is installed?

2) Might we be missing something in the OS build to include Wifi without Connection Manager?

3) Can Connection Manager in WEC 7 (using cmnet.dll) allow for scanning wifi connections and connecting to them using a passed in SSID and Password? If so, is there any documentation/examples to support this?

3) Is there a C# wrapper for Connection Manager?

Thank you all very much for your time and knowledge.